# ng2 completer dataService array value to multiple formarray

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form with multiple form-array. In one I have used ng2 completer which works fine. Now I want to put same completer data value to another form array. Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/aNmCKT1OVRtZTK6rfNMQ?p=preview).

```
medicalItems = 
[{name:'Gloves', number: '1', price: '10.10'},
{name:'Needles', number: '1', price: '22.10'},
{name:'Seasors', number: '1', price: '33.10'}];
```

Here you can find that I want to place price when we select name. e.g. if we select 'Gloves' from ng2 copleter it will place price 10.10 automatically. Is it possible?

Comment: I cannot understand the code in plunker. can you refactor it ?

Comment: Hello Aravind. Its great to see you again. Lets say you have selected name: gloves in drop down it will show gloves 10.10. Now 10.10 is gloves price. Now I want place 10.10 to price form field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML file** add `selected` event in `ng2-completer` tag

```
<ng2-completer 
          [formControl]="po.controls.name"
          [(ngModel)]="myModel.payOffs[i].name"
          class="completer-limit"                       
          [datasource]="dataService2"
          [inputClass]="'form-control'"
          [minSearchLength]="0"
          [placeholder]="'search item'"
          [autoHighlight]="true"
          [fillHighlighted]="false"
          (selected)="onItemSelect($event, i)">
</ng2-completer>
```

**AppComponent** class.

```
onItemSelect(selected:CompleterItem, index: any){
  if(selected)
    this.myModel.payOffs[index].price = selected.originalObject.price;
}
```

Comment: Wow. You are awesome. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: what is "i" there ?

Comment: `i` stands for current index number `let i = index;`